# hibernate fetchmode для FetchType.LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Не могу понять поведение Hibernate если для связанной коллекции будет `FetchType.LAZY`. В гугле описано что такие инструкции вместе являются нежелательными, но почему? Как будет строится запрос если корневая сущность уже была загружена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос будет строиться в рамках сессии. Если она открыта, то вы без проблем можете подгружать проксей. Такой тип как раз наиболее оптимальный для связанных коллекций и используется по умолчанию.